# Align table without Lines

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to align the last row such that the second column starts at the same spot as the 2 upper rows, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it. I know the reason why it's behaving like this is the fact that 'April' has less characters than 'December', but I don't know how to account for it.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
Subperiod 1: & January 2004 - December 2008  & \\
Subperiod 2: & January 2009 - December 2013 & \\
Subperiod 3: & January 2014 - April 2018    & \\
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Sample periods}\label{sampleper}
\end{center}
```

Comment: You need only two columns. Maybe align on left with `{ll}` instead of `ccc`.

Comment: Thank you it worked! You're right I only needed two colums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use only 2 left aligned columns, specified by `{ll}` (in your code, `{ccc}` means 3 centered columns).

Also, I'd use `table` environment, which accept `\caption{}` and `\label{}`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[h]\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll}
Subperiod 1: & January 2004 - December 2008  \\
Subperiod 2: & January 2009 - December 2013  \\
Subperiod 3: & January 2014 - April 2018     
\end{tabular}
\caption{Sample periods}
\label{sampleper}
\end{table}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]